# java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'Name' : value Finn

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, mariadb, serversocket

I have a Java Server Socket on my Debian 10 Server.
I want to read my Mariadb Database, but it didnt work so well.

This is my Command:

```
...
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT " + cCommand[1] +" FROM User WHERE Username = " + cCmdUserData[0] + ";");
...
```

(It sends this Code in SQL:)

```
SELECT [Row] FROM User WHERE Username = [Username];
```

I get an error, but the error contains the answer I want to get:

> java.sql.SQLException: Out of range value for column 'Name' : value Finn

`(SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Username = 'finn737';)`

In Console, it works perfectly but not in Java.

Is there anyone who can help me?

Comment: You need to quote the string: WHERE Username = '" + cCmdUserData[0] + "';"

Comment: You should consider using prepared statements, that offer better performance and safety (and also prevent you from such typos).

Comment: This can occur when the datatypes of the column and the input data don't match. Is ```cCmdUserData[0]``` really ```String```?